# Running sbt inside Intellij got wrong bytecode version

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am working on a project using Intellij/sbt. I have both Java 7/8 installed. It's a java/scala hybrid project. The project is configured (I think) to java 7. I checked Project SDK, Project Language Level, Platform SDK.

Now if I run `sbt assembly` using Intellij -> Views -> Sbt Console, .java file is complied to java 8. If I run sbt assembly in a separate console (outside of Intellij), .java file is compiled to java 7. I use javap to check the bytecode version.

It's almost like I miss a switch inside Intellij to set the bytecode version for sbt but I haven't been able to find it.

What did I miss?

UPDATE:
I added the following to my sbt.build but it didn't help:

```
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7")
```

Another strange thing is my .scala file is compiled to major 50 (java 6). I don't know where this comes from either. Shouldn't it be java 7?

UPATE:
This seems to be a bug in sbt plugin. https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/296

Comment: How can I find `Sbt Console` in my IDEA 15? Did you install anything or are you running a stock IDEA? What's the version?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski View->Tool Windows->SBT Console. It's stock IDEA 15.0.1

Comment: Interesting. I don't have it, but I do have the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the java version inside the sbt file like this:

```
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"
```

or

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8")
```

Here is the sbt reference for that: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Java-Sources.html

Comment: Thanks. I added both options to sbt.build. But still see .java file be compiled to major 52 (java 8).

Answer (score 0):

This is the "SBT Console" I am talking about. I didn't realize it's part of the SBT plugin. It feels like a bug in the plugin.

[image]